# Email to Case and queue assignment

Tags: email2case, queue

I have created a queue and gave email for the queue. I have also added users to the queue. My 2 requirements are:

1) whenever a user is added to queue he should be sent an email alert.

2) In email-to-case whenever an email is sent to a specified email address a case is generated and the above queue is assigned. Now I want to send an email notification to the queue members/ queue email that a case has been generated.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve these two requirements.

Answer (score 0):

@Deepak, you can try achieving this using a workflow field update or email alert. In the queue specify the queue email if this needs to be sent to queue mailer list. Enable the "Send mail to members" checkbox to true. Hope this solves your question!!